# Style for exercises with vertical and top bar

Tags: tabularx, mdframed

Please, I'd like to define an `exercise` environment in the preamble with `mdframed` or `tabularx`, like in the image below.

[image]

I think this environment theorem may solve the problem, just i have to fill in white the right and bottom sides.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 

\newcounter{ex}%[section] \setcounter{theo}{0}
\newenvironment{ex}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{ex}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white]
{\strut \textcolor{red}{Exercice~\theex}};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white]
{\strut \textcolor{red}{Exercice~#1}};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=5pt, innerbottommargin=10pt, linecolor=yellow!60!brown!60!,%
linewidth=2.3pt,topline=true,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax, roundcorner=5pt
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{ex}{application}
ljlklkj
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using `tcolorbox`? This kind of thing is its raison d'etre.

Comment: I have used "`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` " for accented letters and  " `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}`" for colors. Sorry i didn't posted them in the permeable !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amssymb}              
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed} 

\newcounter{ex}%[section] \setcounter{theo}{0}
\newenvironment{ex}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{ex}%
\ifstrempty{#1}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={%
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white]
{\strut \textcolor{red}{Exercice~\theex}};}}
}%
{\mdfsetup{%
frametitle={
\tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=5pt]
\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=white]
{\strut \textcolor{red}{Exercice~#1}};}}%
}%
\mdfsetup{innertopmargin=5pt, innerbottommargin=10pt, linecolor=yellow!60!brown!60!,%
linewidth=2.3pt,topline=true,%
rightline=false,%
bottomline=false,%
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax, roundcorner=0pt
}
\begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
\label{#2}}{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\begin{ex}{application}
ljlklkj
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to edit your existing answer? This doesn't look like a fundamentally different approach, at least at first glance, especially since I take it your other answer doesn't actually realise what the OP wanted.

Comment: I collected some of such latex MWEs.   I replied by posting one of them because by that time MWE was not yet given by OP. Please accept.

Comment: Thank you ! the problem is solved ! I wanted a style like the first image ! and i have posted latter that code in which i need just to delete the right and left lines. coloring and changing round corner is easier !

Answer (score 3):

This is just to-start-with.  It was taken from one of the replies on this forum, I donot remember from where.  Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mdframed} % Add easy frames to paragraphs
\usepackage{lipsum} % For dummy text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse} % Add support for \NewDocumentEnvironment
\definecolor{graylight}{cmyk}{.30,0,0,.67} % define color using xcolor syntax

\newmdenv[ % Define mdframe settings and store as leftrule
  linecolor=graylight,
  linewidth=4pt,
  topline=true,
  bottomline=false,
  rightline=false,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep
]{leftrule}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{example}{O{\textbf{Example:}}} % Define example environment
{\begin{leftrule}\noindent\textcolor{graylight}{#1}\par}
{\end{leftrule}}

\begin{document}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}[Example]
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}
\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: I will start with this, it's useful! Thank you!